# Share property with other components

Tags: angular

I am just learning Angular and I would like to share the value of `currentSection` with other components. So that means my component `sections` includes the property `currentSection` and my component `form` should receive the value of it.

**Component "sections"**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sections',
  templateUrl: './sections.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sections.component.sass']
})
export class SectionsComponent implements OnInit {
  public currentSection: string;

  constructor() { }

  toggleSection(section) {
    this.currentSection = section;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

This is how I tried it:

```
  @Output() public section = new EventEmitter();

  public currentSection: string;

  constructor() { }

  toggleSection(section) {
    this.currentSection = section;
    this.section.emit(section);
  }
```

**HTML from component "table"**

```
<form [ngClass]="section">
```

But I get the error **Unresolved variable or type section**.

How can I fix this?

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3tbxpz)

Comment: @lealceldeiro I have updated my question. Hope that it's more clear now.

Comment: Can you paste your HTML code where you call the app-sections component ?

Comment: @MichaelDesigaud sure, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3tbxpz

Comment: @lealceldeiro You could do the following: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tzq8kc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @MichaelDesigaud thank you so much. That helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost done:

In your `app-form` add an input like:

```js
@Input() section: string;
```

And then share the section from the `app-sections` to `app-form` in the `AppComponent` (which is acting like a Mediator)

```html
<app-sections (section)="onSectionChanged($event)"/app-sections>
<app-form [section]="section"></app-form>
```

```js
export class AppComponent  {
  section: string

  onSectionChanged(section) {
    this.section = section;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to `@Input` the section to form component. You need to have section as `@Input()` in form component:

```
 @Input() section: string;
```

and from the parent `app-sections` template share the same like this:

You have the error because `section` is defined as an Output Event and it's not defined in form-component as input.

Check this [example for more details on @input](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

Answer (score 0):

Make below changes and you should be good to go..check your console log

Update your sections component(child component) ts

```
@Output() public currentSection = new EventEmitter<string>();


toggleSection(section) {    
this.currentSection.emit(section);
console.log(section);
}
```

Update your forms component ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-form',
template: `<app-sections (currentSection)='displaySection($event)'></app-sections>`
})

export class FormComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {

}

displaySection(section) {
    console.log("Section ",section);
}
}
```

Update your forms component html

```
<form></form>
```

Update your app component html

```
<app-form></app-form>
```